# Pyspark Groupby with aggregation Round value to 2 decimals

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 80.65,"abc"), 
    ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 100,"abc"),
    ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 65,"def"), 
    ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 78.02,"def")
]).toDF("date", "percent","device")
```

I need to apply groupby on with avg

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('date', StringType(), True),
    StructField('percent', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('device', StringType(), True)
]) 
dtaDF.groupBy("device").agg(round(mean("percent").alias("y"),2))
```

I'm facing the below exception

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: Can you rerun by changing `100` to `100.00` and `65` to `65.00` ?

Comment: Here I can change. But those are dynamic values. How can I change?

Comment: Load them as strings and cast them to float / double

Comment: Yeah. I have casted them to float like float(val). when applying the query with round facing the same exception

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
...     ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 80.65,"abc"), 
...     ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 100.00,"abc"),
...     ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 65.00,"def"), 
...     ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 78.02,"def")
... ]).toDF("date", "percent","device")
>>> schema = StructType([
...     StructField('date', StringType(), True),
...     StructField('percent', FloatType(), True),
...     StructField('device', StringType(), True)
... ]) 

>>> df.groupBy("device").agg(round(mean("percent"),2).alias("y")).show()
+------+--------+         
|device|       y|
+------+--------+
|   def|   71.51|
|   abc|   90.33|
+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use UDFs:

```
@pandas_udf("float", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def mean_udf(v):
    return round(v.mean(), 2)
spark.udf.register("mean_udf", mean_udf)

dfStackOverflow = spark.createDataFrame([
     ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 80.65,"abc"), 
     ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 100.00,"abc"),
     ("2017-Dec-08 00:00 - 2017-Dec-09 00:00", 65.00,"def"), 
     ("2017-Dec-09 00:00 - 2017-Dec-10 00:00", 78.02,"def")
 ], 
 schema = StructType([
     StructField('date', StringType(), True),
     StructField('percent', FloatType(), True),
     StructField('device', StringType(), True)
 ]))

dfStackOverflow.groupBy("device").agg({"percent":"mean_udf"}).show()

+------+-----------------+
|device|mean_udf(percent)|
+------+-----------------+
|   abc|            90.32|
|   def|            71.51|
+------+-----------------+
```